# Autostart redshift-gtk in Window Maker and prevent it to run twice

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager, redshift

I struggled to launch **redshift-gtk** at **Window Maker** startup.

Moreover, editing a **dockable ico**n would **not prevent** the app to be **load twice** (I noticed it's the case at WMaker startup, I don't know what it happens). Also it may stay "greyed out" since no window will appear.

So, **`GNUStep/Library/WindowMaker/autostart`** may be the better place.

(**`xinitrc`**, may not be the good place since WindowMaker is not yet loaded at this step.)

How could I make it autostart while preventing it to be loaded **twice**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple piped command in `autostart` file solves the issue:

```
ps x | grep -v grep | grep -q "redshift-gtk" || redshift-gtk &
```

Don't forget the ampersand `&` to let Window Maker fulfills its duty.